# How to asynchronously non-block schedule task or event triggered in python?

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I have written a sample code of my problem. The input message are split into fixed chunks and mixed using an intentional random delay. However, `sleep()` is blocking and won't run the next task. Is this possible on a single thread or do I have to resort to multi-threading?

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep

def delay_message(split_message, delay):
    #sleep(delay) #this blocks
    print("Shuffled message: {} and time: {}". format(split_message, delay)) 

def main():
    message = raw_input('Input: ')

    #padding
    difference = len(message) % 5
    message=message.ljust(len(message)+5-difference, "0")

    for i in range(0, len(message), 5):
        delay = randint(0, 5)
        split_message = message[i:i+5]
        delay_message(split_message, delay)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: have a look at [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html). if it is really just a non-blocking sleep you need, that might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sleep` will indeed block its running thread.

It is possible to make it non-blocking by using libraries like [`gevent`](http://www.gevent.org/intro.html#example). Gevent can also patch `time.sleep` and make it non-blocking and also has its own non-blocking sleep. It can also patch the entire python standard library to make it non-blocking - socket, time, threading etc, see [documentation](http://www.gevent.org/intro.html#monkey-patching).

The above example can be made co-operatively concurrent with gevent like so:

```
from random import randint
from gevent import sleep, spawn, joinall

def delay_message(split_message, delay):
    # Gevent's sleep yields the event loop for
    # duration of delay rather than blocking the running thread
    sleep(delay)
    print("Shuffled message: {} and time: {}". format(split_message, delay)) 

def main():
    message = raw_input('Input: ')

    #padding
    difference = len(message) % 5
    message=message.ljust(len(message)+5-difference, "0")

    greenlets = []
    # This will create len(message)/5 number of greenlets,
    # which corresponds to the concurrency level.
    # Greenlets all run under one thread so there is no CPU
    # overhead here.
    for i in range(0, len(message), 5):
        delay = randint(0, 5)
        split_message = message[i:i+5]
        greenlets.append(spawn(delay_message, split_message, delay))
    # Wait for all greenlets to complete, raise any exceptions
    joinall(greenlets, raise_error=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The constraint is that CPU bound tasks cannot be run in greenlets as they would block the event loop and all other greenlets.

As long as what is run in greenlets is I/O bound, like passing messages in sockets or generators, other greenlets et al, greenlets are appropriate. For CPU bound tasks, use native threads or multiple processes.

There are other alternatives like `asyncio` (Py3 only). Gevent is compatible with Py2 and 3 and has very high performance, backed by native code extensions.

Comment: Thank you, that is very interesting. By CPU-bound, do you mean if delay_message was performing a heavy operation? Or could you give me an example of what you mean by so

Comment: CPU bound task would be anything that is blocked on executing code on the CPU. Examples would be audio/video encoding and decoding, image processing and so on, basically anything that involves code running on the CPU. I/O bound tasks would be reading/writing streams over network, network request handling, disk I/O and so on. Networking can be handled by threads as well but that means a lot of CPU overhead (increased CPU usage, reduced max concurrency) for something that is not in fact limited by the CPU. For that, co-operative multitasking, aka asynchronous I/O, is a better fit.

Comment: that makes sense thanks for that. Gevent does not have `usleep() or nanosleep()` with high degree of accuracy. Is there a way to handle this with the current method? Or could you advise another way that I could look into

Comment: `sleep(0.01)` and similar work fine for sub-second sleeps. About as accurate as anything else timer based.